# update listbox text values dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, observablecollection

I have found the way add or delete the item in listbox which takes advantages of the Observable Collection. But i want to update all the particular binding property values in the listbox for example all the textblocks only in listbox to update. Here is the example for adding  item in listbox, but i want to update the values:binding Name on button click outside listbox so how can i achieve that?

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillListBox();
    }
    MovieList Mov = new MovieList();
    private void FillListBox()
    {
        listBox1.ItemsSource = Mov;
        listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        listBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(listBox1_SelectionChanged);
    }
    void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mov.Add(new Movie { Name = "Ghillli", Actor = "Vijay" });
    }
}
public class Movie
{
    public string Actor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MovieList : ObservableCollection
{
    public MovieList()
    {
        Add(new Movie { Name = "Kaavalan", Actor = "Vijay", });
        Add(new Movie { Name = "Velayutham", Actor = "Vijay", });
        Add(new Movie { Name = "7th Sense", Actor = "Surya", });
        Add(new Movie { Name = "Billa 2", Actor = "Ajith Kumar", });
        Add(new Movie { Name = "Nanban", Actor = "Vijay", });
    }
}
```

so how to update all values binding Name Property in listbox without nulling itemsource and rebinding all values and only updating Name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in code as below:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Actor { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MovieList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mevent = PropertyChanged;
        if (mevent != null)
        {
            mevent(this, e);
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Movie> Movieitems = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
    public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieItems
    {
        get { return Movieitems; }
        set
        {
            if (Movieitems == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            Movieitems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MovieItems"));
        }
    }

    public MovieList()
    {
        Movieitems.Add(new Movie { Name = "Kaavalan", Actor = "Vijay", });
        Movieitems.Add(new Movie { Name = "Velayutham", Actor = "Vijay", });
        Movieitems.Add(new Movie { Name = "7th Sense", Actor = "Surya", });
        Movieitems.Add(new Movie { Name = "Billa 2", Actor = "Ajith Kumar", });
        Movieitems.Add(new Movie { Name = "Nanban", Actor = "Vijay", });
    }
}
```

And add `item dynamically in listbox` in `listBox1_SelectionChanged` as below:

```
Mov.MovieItems.Add(new Movie { Name = "Ghillli", Actor = "Vijay" });
```

**Edit:**

For update existing Name property

```
Mov.MovieItems[SelectedIndexValue] = new Movie { Name = "Ghillli", Actor = "Vijay" };
```

SelectedIndexValue = 0,1,2,3... etc.

For update `Name` property of colletion

```
Mov.MovieItems[SelectedIndexValue].Name = "Ghillli";
```

Comment: i want to do update existing all Name property and that to on  only name property @smoother sillent

Comment: ok this updates all values for the particular item, is it possible to only update Name property not Actor and that to all Name property

Comment: @SD7 You mean update `Mov.MovieItems` all collection item name property.